# Add row to a table with tablesorter and pager

Tags: jquery, tablesorter, pager

I'm trying to add a row dynamically to a tablesorter table with a pager. Whenever i do, all other pages get removed. How can i add it? alternatively, how can i remove the oager from a table and return it to its normal state? that would also help. Right now, i am trying to append a row, then i have tried:

```
    $("table#inventory").trigger("update");
    $("table#inventory").trigger("appendCache");
    $("table#inventory").trigger("sorton", [[0, 0]]);
```

and

```
    $("#pager *").unbind('click');
    $("table#inventory").trigger("update");
    $("table#inventory").trigger("appendCache");
    $("table#inventory").trigger("sorton", [sorting]);
    $("table#inventory").tablesorterPager({
        container: $("#pager")
    });
```

and

```
$('table#inventory, table#inventory *, #pager, #pager *').unbind();
$("table#inventory").tablesorter({
    debug: false,
    sortList: [[0, 0]]
}) .tablesorterPager({
    container: $("#pager")
});
```

based on what i have read online at various forums. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a fork of the tablesorter plugin on my [github](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter) site. I noticed your question and recently added the ability to add a row to the table while the pager is active. As you stated above, using the "update" method doesn't work because it updates the cache to include only the visible rows.

I've also added a destroy method, if you still need that :)

Here is the [demo page](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-pager.html).